# Creating dependent dropdowns in magento admin

Tags: magento, admin, cascadingdropdown

Is there any way to create a dependent drop down in Magento Admin in my custom form?
I have to display product categories in a drop down based on a store selected in its previous drop down.

Do I need Ajax for that?

Comment: I think you'll need to better explain what you are trying to accomplish to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add dependencies to Your custom form. It's well described here: http://www.pixlpitch.com/adding-field-dependency-in-magento-admin/